# How to replace a string value with the means of a column's groups in the entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset with 400columns and 30,000 rows. The dataset is all numerical but some columns have weird string values in them (denoted as "#?") instead of being blank. This changes the dtypes of the columns that have "#?" into object type. (150 columns object dtype)

I need to convert all the columns into float or int dtypes, and then fill the normal NaN values in the data, with means of a column's groups. (e.g: means of X, means of Y in each column)

```
col1 col2 col3
X    21    32 
X    NaN   3
Y    Nan   5
```

My end goal is to apply this to the entire data:

```
df.groupby("col1").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

But I can't apply this for the columns that have "#?" in them, they get dropped.
I tried replacing the #? with a numerical value, and then convert all the columns into float dtype, which works, but the replaced values also should be included in the above code.

I thought about replacing #? with an weird value like -123.456 so that it doesn't get mixed with actual data points, and maybe replace all the -123.456 with the means of column groups but the -123.456 would need to be excluded from the mean. But I just don't know how that would even work. If I convert it back to NaN again, the dtype changes back to object.

I think the best way to go about it would be directly replacing the #? with the column group means.

Any ideas?

edit: I'm so dumb lol

```
df=df.replace('#?', '').astype(float, errors = 'ignore')
```

this works.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    X   21    32
1    X   #?     3
2    Y  NaN     5

df = (df.set_index('col1')
        .replace(r'#\?', np.nan, regex=True)
        .astype(float)
        .groupby("col1")
        .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())))
print (df)
      col2  col3
col1            
X     21.0  32.0
X     21.0   3.0
Y      NaN   5.0
```

Comment: how would you do this, if you wanted to add an exception for some columns? Meaning that, if you had 100 columns, and you don't want to fill missing values for 2 of the columns. (lets call them col2 and col3)

Comment: @prof31 it depends what values are in columns. Because solution use aggregation, so one possible solution is use `df.set_index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] )`and then change `.groupby("col1")` to `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] )`. But sometimes need another aggregation function fitbthese new columns. The best see input data and expected output.