# How to drop columns, do operation on remaining columns, then insert back the dropped columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset. I want to apply something on all the columns except for 2.

I dropped the 2 columns and created a separate dataframe, then tried merging the dataframes after the operation is applied.

I tried appending, merging, joining the two dataframes but they all created duplicate rows. Appending doubled the row count, and changed the dropped columns.

I just want to add back the 2 columns to the initial dataframe unchanged. Any help?

```
df= col1 col2 col3... col100
     1    2   3         100

df2=df.loc[:,['col2', 'col3']]
df.drop(columns=['col2', 'col3'], inplace=True)
```

Then do what I needed to do to df.

Now I want to merge df and df2.

Comment: `df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)`, however there is no way to know the original order

Comment: I get: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects –

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
cols = ['col2', 'col3']
df2 = df[cols]
df.drop(columns=cols, inplace=True)
# do something
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

This will work as long as you didn't remove rows from either dataframes or changed their order

Comment: I get: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: On which line??

Comment: on     df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)

Comment: 1. made a small correction in the second row above. 2. The code should work. What alterations do you do in the data?

Comment: I applied this answer to the data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73643833/how-to-replace-a-string-value-with-the-means-of-a-columns-groups-in-the-entire

Comment: As I wrote in the answer above - a major change will not allow you to contact. For merging you must leave a common column in BOTH dataframes

Comment: OK thanks. I tried leaving a common column that I know did not get affected by the applied operation. And when I merge the two dataframes on the common column, I get duplicate rows. Any advice on that?

Comment: meaning that I added col4 to df2, but didnt drop col4 from df. then applied the operation. col4 shouldnt be impacted by the operation. but when I do 'df.merge(df2, on='col4', how='left')' , the row count gets multiplied by like 85 lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247888/discussion-between-gtomer-and-prof31).